# Show $T\colon M_n(F)\to M_n(F)$ is isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the mapping  $T\colon M_n(F)  \to M_n(F)$  defined as as $B \mapsto T(B)=AB$.

I have shown it is linear transformation and if $A$ is invertible then it is one one. But how do I show it is onto? For onto every matrix should be represented as product $AB$ for some $B$. Is it possible?

Comment: To show it is onto you need to show every matrix has an origin. I think it is pretty easy to calculate the origin, given that A is invertible.

Comment: @JonesY  What do you mean by "every matrix has an origin"?

Comment: @Learner question asks if A is invertible then is T isomorphism and what about converse?

Comment: I think what JonesY means is that every matrix comes from a matrix in the domain. The matrix in the domain that maps to a given matrix will be its ``origin" -- not the normal terminology. But it makes sense.

Comment: @Learner : The transformation is from the set of matrices to itself. The transformation will be onto the set, if for every $M_y$ there exists $M_x$  such that $A\cdot M_x=M_y$

Comment: @JonesY Ofcourse,its just the definition of onto map.I don't understand the meaning of "every matrix has a origin".By that did you mean just the definition of onto map?If not ,then what is the origin of a matrix?

Comment: i ment just by the definiton. anyway just multiply with $A^(-1)$ another way could be to see what is the kernel of the transformation. again, if A is invertible then there is only one vektor in the kernel, thus the transformation is onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onto means every matrix in the range needs to come from a matrix in the domain. However, since $A$ is invertible a given $B$ will come from $A^{-1}B$.

Given a $B \in M_{n}(F)$ there exists a matrix $A^{-1}B$ such that $T(A^{-1}B)=A(A^{-1}B)=B$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that any linear transformation $T:V \to V$ is one one iff $T$ is onto.($V$ is finite dimensional).Proof of this fact is direct application of rank Nullity theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U$ be the transformation $B\mapsto A^{-1}B$ (which exists because $A$ is invertible and is linear by the same argument as $T$). Then $U\circ T=T\circ U=\operatorname{Id}_{M_n(F)}$, i.e., $T$ is an isomorphism with inverse $U$.

*Remark:* Note that in this argument we do not use that the space $M_n(F)$ is finite-dimensional, instead we explicitly use the existence of a (two-sided) inverse of $A$.

Comment: Nice one,I wish I should have give this solution.